# PostgreSQL 9.4.6 under RHEL 7 - Extensive logfile because of log_statement_stats - Can't turn off

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I got a newly installed database (PG 9.4.6 / RHEL 7) which logfile grows rapidly.

Most entries are like

```
2016-03-03 10:33:29.259 CET [56868] user@db STATEMENT:  SELECT field1 AS a1, field2 AS a2, field3 AS a3, field4 AS a4, field5 AS a5, field6 AS a6, MSISDN AS a7, field8 AS a8, RETRY_COUNT AS a9 FROM table WHERE ((field3 <= $1) AND (field8 IS NULL)) ORDER BY field3 ASC LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3
2016-03-03 10:33:29.259 CET [56868] user@db LOG:  EXECUTE MESSAGE STATISTICS
2016-03-03 10:33:29.259 CET [56868] user@db DETAIL:  ! system usage stats:
        !       0.000006 elapsed 0.000000 user 0.000000 system sec
        !       [0.526408 user 0.112125 sys total]
        !       0/0 [0/0] filesystem blocks in/out
        !       0/0 [0/1281] page faults/reclaims, 0 [0] swaps
        !       0 [0] signals rcvd, 0/0 [0/0] messages rcvd/sent
        !       0/0 [3516/0] voluntary/involuntary context switches
```

I read through the documentation and found out, that it should be one of the log_*_stats parameters and despite the missing config entry in the postgresql.conf and postgresql.auto.conf

```
> egrep "log_.*stats" postgresql.*conf
postgresql.conf:#log_parser_stats = off
postgresql.conf:#log_planner_stats = off
postgresql.conf:#log_executor_stats = off
postgresql.conf:#log_statement_stats = off
```

the running instance shows that the parameter is set to "on".

```
> echo "show log_statement_stats" | psql
 log_statement_stats
---------------------
 on
```

I tried to change it by applying an "ALTER SYSTEM", but it doesn't help. The parameter stays "on".

I also reloaded the database (*pg_ctl reload*) and restarted it (its a pacemaker resource, so *pcs resource restart postgre_db*) - But nothing happens.

How do I turn off this setting?

Comment: What happens if you edit `postgresql.conf` manually and un-comment those parameters ? (instead of using `ALTER TABLE`)

Comment: Exactly the same. It does not matter, if I remove the comment in postgresql.conf or use the ALTER SYSTEM to add the respective line in postgresql.auto.conf. I also restarted the db, but the result is the same: The setting stays enabled.

Comment: Do you have the `auto_explain` module installed? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html

Comment: No, the only installed module is pg_stat_statements.

Comment: From `psql`, please issue a `\drds` command.  Do you see `log_statement_stats` listed?

Comment: postgres=# \drds
No settings found.

Comment: Could the application set the parameter? It is a test environment...
But then the question is why the parameter is set globally, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple levels where you configuration options are set in PostgreSQL:

1. system defaults
2. values specified in `postgresql.conf` or the startup command line
3. values preset for a database, user (maybe others, too) using, for example, `ALTER DATABASE ... SET {option} ...`
4. values set for the current session

Going down the list from 2., you have fewer and fewer options to set.  Furthermore, there are some that can only be set by a superuser (`log_statement_stats`) being one of them.

At the same time, the lower in the list an option is set, the higher its precedence: a session-level setting will override all the upper levels.

Speaking specifically about `log_statement_stats`, it is possible to set it from a session - but only a superuser can do it.  If your application connects with a superuser role (which is not really recommended), it can set this as one of the first things after obtaining the connection.  Look for it in your sources.

### Ways of changing settings

The numbers refer to the levels listed above.

1. Supplying defaults at [compile time](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-procedure.html)
2. [`ALTER SYSTEM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html) - this will store the settings in a `postgresql.auto.conf` file, which will be read in addition to `postgresql.conf`.
3. [`ALTER DATABASE ... SET ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html) or [`ALTER ROLE ... [IN DATABASE database_name] SET ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html).  Some settings can be set on database objects (like tables, functions, etc.), too.
4. [`SET \[SESSION\] ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) - to change things for the current connection (often dubbed 'session').  There is even a way to change things until the end of the current transaction: `SET LOCAL ...`

Comment: Ok, you were on the right track. It was a setting on "database"-Level. It was activated in both databases (postgres and application). Is there a quick way to find out those kind of settings? The show commands gave the correct output, but not the place where this setting is set.

Comment: `\drds [PATRN1 [PATRN2]] list per-database role settings` - not sure why it did not show it.  Currently, I have no better idea, but will probably check it later.

Comment: Did you find anything? Today I had to change this setting again on databaselevel and didn't find any hint if it is configured?